# How do I pass the parameter in every call to a react.js class method to a modal contained inside it?

Tags: reactjs

I have two classes. In the `render()` method of `Timeslots`, when I pass the parameter to `this.colhour` and use it in an instance of `TsModal`, `modalid` is always assigned as `'11:00-11:30'`. How do I assign `modalid` as the unique parameter that is passed in the function call?

```jsx
class Timeslots extends Component {
  popoverHoverFocus() {
    return (
      <Popover id="popover-trigger-hover-focus" title="Table status">
        <strong>P1 -> </strong> <br />
        <strong>P2 -> </strong> <br />
        <strong>S1 -> </strong> <br />
        <strong>S2 -> </strong> <br />
        <strong>S3 -> </strong> <br />
      </Popover>
    );
  }

  colhour(time) {
    return (
      <Col className='halfhour' xs={4} md={1}>
        <TsModal modalid = {time} show={this.state.show} onhide={this.handleClose} onclick={this.handleClose} />
        <OverlayTrigger overlay={this.popoverHoverFocus()}>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small" onClick={this.handleShow}>
            {time} 
          </Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
      </Col>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <br></br>
        <Row className="timeslot">
          {this.colhour('10:00-10:30')}
          {this.colhour('10:30-11:00')}
          {this.colhour('11:00-11:30')}
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

```jsx
class TsModal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onhide}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Book Tables</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>            
          <hr />
          <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small" href={'http://localhost:4000/?id=' + this.props.modalid}>Pool table 1</Button>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onclick}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz example of it? your current code looks ok

Comment: [this is my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2tcbkk)
But I think the `react-bootstrap` library is not rendering on stackblitz, I am not sure of the reason. 
It is working on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way to pass the value of the button that is clicked to the `TsModal` instance.
I made a handler function `handleButPush` and passed `keeptime`to it. Then I stored that value in a state `buttonPush` and passed the state value to the TsModal instance. By this, `modalid` is assigned the different `keeptime` value everytime.

```
this.state = {
  show: false, 
  buttonPush: 'invalid',
  list : [],  
  popoverlist : [{status: "Available"},{status: "Available"},{status:"Available"},{status: "Available"},{status:"Available"}]
};

handleButPush(val) {
this.setState({ buttonpush: val });
}

colhour(keeptime,butdisable) {
return(  
    <Col className='halfhour' xs={4} md={1}>
      <TsModal modalid = {this.state.buttonpush} show={this.state.show} onhide={this.handleClose} onclick={this.handleClose} />
        <OverlayTrigger overlay = {() => {this.popoverHoverFocus({keeptime},{butdisable})} } >
          <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small"  onClick={() => { this.handleShow(); this.handleButPush({keeptime}); }}>
            {keeptime} 
          </Button>
        </OverlayTrigger>
    </Col>
);
}
```